# How to upload to dropbox?

Tags: android, dropbox

I am creating an app in android in which i want to give a  functionality to upload file to drop box. Please suggest that is drop box application required to upload file or we can upload without app install

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/setup#android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("file/*"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.getPath()));  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "title");
```

Send Intent with Action Intent.ACTION_SEND. It will be work if you have dropbox app on your device.

Good luck!

Comment: i have used some apps in which there is the functionality to upload to drop box without chooser

Comment: As I know, dropbox has broadcast receiver that can catch this Intent. In other way, just think, how can you achive it? I realy dont see other ways achive it. One case if dropbox have own special Intent Action but I dont know about it.

Comment: thanks for your effort